# Free forecast vs cycled model runs

Tags: models, atmosphere-modelling

What is the difference between a free forecast and a cycled model run?  [This GFS wiki](https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/global-workflow/wiki/Run-Global-Workflow#run-setup-scripts-to-generate-experiment) mentions both, but does not define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool, didn't realize that the GFS was on Github.

[Looking on down the wiki](https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/global-workflow/wiki/Run-Global-Workflow#view-experiment-output), it seems like the "free-forecast" is associated with the deterministic model, while the "cycled" is associated with the Ensemble Kalman Filter. That is, the free-forecast is not constrained by data assimilation algorithms- it can just start from a restart file and go. A cycled run, however, needs multiple runs, as well as data.

This is all speculation based on naming conventions. If you really want an answer, perhaps [asking the code developer](https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/global-workflow/wiki)?